# Sort array of objects according to multiple fields

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like

```
const hotels = [
  { hotelName: "a", price: 2000, rating: 3 },
  { hotelName: "b", price: 1000, rating: 2 },
  { hotelName: "c", price: 6000, rating: 3 },
  { hotelName: "d", price: 700, rating: 4 },
  { hotelName: "e", price: 3000, rating: 5 },
];

function sortHotels(value) {
  let sortedHotel= hotels.sort((a, b) => 
    b.rating - a.rating
  );
  
  console.log(sortedHotel)
}

sortHotels(1)
sortHotels(-1)
```

So until now I was sorting this `acc` to rating in descending order, but now I want a little tweak .

As you can see now in the

> function `sortHotels`

I am passing "value" as a parameter and according to that I want to sort

For eg -  if value passed is -1. Sort the data according to rating in descending order and then if the ratings of any data is same, then sort them acc. to their price in descending order

If value passed is 1. Sort the data according to rating in ascending order and then if the ratings of any data is same, then sort them acc. to their price in ascending order.

So I am confused over adding multiple condition in sort method here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
const hotels = [
  { hotelName: "a", price: 2000, rating: 3 },
  { hotelName: "b", price: 1000, rating: 2 },
  { hotelName: "c", price: 6000, rating: 3 },
  { hotelName: "d", price: 700, rating: 4 },
  { hotelName: "e", price: 3000, rating: 5 },
];

function sortHotels(value) {
  if ( value < 0 )
    return hotels.sort((a, b) => 
      ((b.rating - a.rating) || (b.price - a.price))
    );

  return hotels.sort((a, b) => 
    ((a.rating - b.rating) || (a.price - b.price))
  );
}

console.log(sortHotels(1))
console.log(sortHotels(-1))

// If you'll notice closely we are either using `a - b` or `b - a`
// To simplify the logic you can do something like this

function sortHotelsSmart(value) {
  return hotels.sort((a, b) => 
    ((a.rating - b.rating) || (a.price - b.price)) * value
  );
}

console.log(sortHotelsSmart(1))
console.log(sortHotelsSmart(-1))
```

**FYI**: Sorting is done in place and mutates the actual array so you might want to use sort on `[...hotels]`.

Comment: Nice answer. Seems we had a lot of the same ideas. :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const hotels = [{
    hotelName: "a",
    price: 2000,
    rating: 3
  },
  {
    hotelName: "b",
    price: 1000,
    rating: 2
  },
  {
    hotelName: "c",
    price: 6000,
    rating: 3
  },
  {
    hotelName: "d",
    price: 700,
    rating: 4
  },
  {
    hotelName: "e",
    price: 3000,
    rating: 5
  },
];

function sortHotels(value) {
  if (value === -1) {
    return [...hotels].sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.rating === b.rating) {
        return b.price - a.price;
      } else return b.rating - a.rating;
    });
  } else if (value === 1) {
    return [...hotels].sort((a, b) => {
      if (b.rating === a.rating) {
        return a.price - b.price;
      } else return a.rating - b.rating;
    });
  }
}

console.log(sortHotels(1));
console.log(sortHotels(-1));
```

Comment: Yes, making a copy of the array would be a more robust solution in many scenarios. It would certainly avoid the side effect of sorting the original array in place. I personally chose to put all logic in a single `sort` call's function argument, but multiple sort calls would work just fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Long live closures. You could just use the `value` variable inside your sort callback's body. Something like this:

```js
(a, b) => ((a.rating - b.rating) || (a.price - b.price)) * value
```

This callback first tries to determine the sort order based on rating (`a.rating - b.rating`). In case of an equal rating, the result of the substraction is `0`, which is a falsy value. In that case the sort order based on price (`a.price - b.price`) will kick in due to the OR operator. The final result is multiplied with the `value` parameter value to reverse sorting when its value is negative.

Mind that the `Array.prototype.sort` method sorts the array in place. Your original `hotels` array will be sorted as well. To avoid that, you could make a copy of the original array before you sort it. For example by using the spread operator: `[...hotels]`.

In case you want to continue processing the sorted hotels array, I would personally return that sorted array from the `sortHotels` function. And I would try to avoid side effects (like writing to the console) inside the `sortHotels` function as well.

This would be the end result:

```js
const hotels = [
  { hotelName: "a", price: 2000, rating: 3 },
  { hotelName: "b", price: 1000, rating: 2 },
  { hotelName: "c", price: 6000, rating: 3 },
  { hotelName: "d", price: 700, rating: 4 },
  { hotelName: "e", price: 3000, rating: 5 },
];

function sortHotels(value) {
  return [...hotels].sort((a, b) =>
    ((a.rating - b.rating) || (a.price - b.price)) * value
  );
}

console.log(sortHotels(1));
console.log(sortHotels(-1));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for something like this ?

```js
const hotels = [
  { hotelName: "a", price: 2000, rating: 3 },
  { hotelName: "b", price: 1000, rating: 2 },
  { hotelName: "c", price: 6000, rating: 3 },
  { hotelName: "d", price: 700, rating: 4 },
  { hotelName: "e", price: 3000, rating: 5 },
];

function sortHotels(value) {
  let sortedHotel= hotels.sort((a, b) => {
  
    if(value === 1) {
        return a.rating - b.rating
    } else {
        return b.rating - a.rating
    }
  }
    
  );
  
  console.log(sortedHotel)
}

sortHotels(1)
sortHotels(-1)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right that you could just use the `value` parameter inside the sort callback's argument function. However, you did not include sorting on the price when the ratings are the same. The OP asked for that as well, since they probably didn't know how to do that.